# Ignite messaging: Is there a new style for async messaging?

Tags: ignite

According to [`IgniteMessaging` javadoc](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/), `withAsync` method is deprecated.

What's the new api to send messages asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no such API. We have to use `withAsync` - it still works.

I've filed a ticket to add missing `sendAsync` methods:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-19017

Comment: I was hoping you would find my question :D

Any chance you could take a look at this related question as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75723994/ignite-messaging-how-to-know-if-an-ordered-message-was-dropped-due-to-timeout

Comment: @Mohathealmightycamel I'm subscribed to ignite tag and check all the questions, but that one is out of my knowledge area