# Ignite messaging: How to know if an ordered message was dropped due to timeout?

Tags: ignite

According to [IgniteMessaging#sendOrdered() javadoc](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/):

> If timeout expires, then all ordered messages for a given topic that have not arrived yet will be skipped. When (and if) expired messages actually do arrive, they will be ignored.

Is there anyway to be notified if this happens ?

Checking [Ignite events documentation](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/events/events), there is no mention of any events releatd to messages or message queues.